# Use paste command with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use paste command in order to paste some part of string into command group_by from dyplyr. This how is look like code normally without paste.

```
library(dplyr)
   DATA1<-DATA%>%
dplyr::group_by(id_n,gross_income)%>%
dplyr::summarize(gross_i=sum(gross_i)
```

So now I want to use paste command, and I try with this line of code.

```
  query_type1<-"id_n,gross_income"
```

Next step is to implement this line of code in code above.

```
   DATA1<-DATA%>%
dplyr::group_by(query_type1)%>%
dplyr::summarize(gross_i=sum(gross_i)
```

But unfortunately this don't give me good result. So can anybody help me how to fix this line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already suggested have column names as vector instead of one comma-separated string.

```
query_type1<- c("id_n","gross_income")
```

You can then use `across` in `group_by` :

```
library(dplyr)

DATA%>%
  group_by(across(query_type1)) %>%
  summarize(gross_i=sum(gross_i)
```

Answer (score 3):

try it like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
gr <- syms(c("vs", "am"))
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(!!!gr) %>% 
  summarise(sum_mpg = sum(mpg))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'vs' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   vs [2]
#>      vs    am sum_mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     0     0    181.
#> 2     0     1    118.
#> 3     1     0    145.
#> 4     1     1    199.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the `rlang` package within the tidyverse. `exprs` "defuses" an expression, which means it can take values (that don't need to be in quotes) and returns the R expression describing how to make the value. `!!!`, called "unquote-splice", takes a list of arguments and inserts them in the place of `!!!`

```
library(tidyverse)

gvars <- exprs(gear, carb)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(!!!gvars)
```